# Using Google's example code and getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, xml, google-ads-api

I want to run this code to test the Google Ads API - The code should download a CSV file, however an error shows and I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't include using Maven.

The page I am using for all the example code is https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/samples-use-cases

I am trying to get the last 7 days data for some keywords in the Google Ads Account so that we can analyse the data automatically in a java program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential.
    Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
            .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
            .fromFile()
            .build()
            .generateCredential();

    // Construct an AdWordsSession.
    AdWordsSession session = new AdWordsSession.Builder()
            .fromFile()
            .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
            .build();

    // Create report definition.
    ReportDefinition reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
    reportDefinition.setReportName("Criteria performance report #" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    reportDefinition.setDateRangeType(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.LAST_7_DAYS);
    reportDefinition.setReportType(ReportDefinitionReportType.KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);
    reportDefinition.setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat.CSV);

    Selector selector = new Selector();
    selector.getFields().addAll(Lists.newArrayList("CampaignId",
            "AdGroupId",
            "Id",
            "CriteriaType",
            "Criteria",
            "FinalUrls",
            "Impressions",
            "Clicks",
            "Cost"));

    ReportDownloadResponse response =
            new ReportDownloader(session).downloadReport(reportDefinition);
    response.saveToFile("reportFile");

}
```

Error Message is: 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEYo3.png

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.utils.v201809.XmlReportDefinitionRequest.(XmlReportDefinitionRequest.java:32)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.utils.v201809.ReportDownloader.downloadReport(ReportDownloader.java:65)
    at main.main(main.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 3 more

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please add the exception message as text instead of image over here?

Comment: Added as text below the image!